# PHP sendmail stalls processing in ActiveCollab

Tags: php, bash, sendmail, activecollab

I am a developer in a shop that runs ActiveCollab as a project management tool. Activecollab sends out e-mail notifications when tickets are updated/completed/etc.

Right now, the page is "halted" until the e-mail is sent, which slows down our workflow as it takes 2-3 seconds on average to send out the mail. When trying to close several tickets at once (having a few tabs open), it gets really bad.

Is there any way to get the e-mails to be "queued up" or somehow otherwise set up the system so that the process isn't blocked while mail is sending? Please note that hacking the code isn't really an option... but i'm fine writing a "pass through" bash script. Also note that if a notification doesn't go out, it's not a big deal... I'm fine with losing one or two here and there if it speeds everything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[activeCollab 3](http://www.activecollab.com/version-3/) (currently in beta) introduces "in the background" mailing. When mailer is configured to send messages in the background instead of instantly (default), it will add it to the mailing queue. Messages from queue are sent to recipients when frequently scheduled tasks is triggered.

More info on scheduled tasks is available here: [Scheduled Tasks](http://www.activecollab.com/docs/manuals/admin/configuration/scheduled-tasks). Information on different mailing types will be provided when activeCollab 3 gets out of beta and we publish new [Admin's Guide](http://www.activecollab.com/docs/admin).

**UPDATE:** Article has been updated a while ago, but I forgot to update this comment. Updated version of the article that covers outgoing email in activeCollab is available here:

https://www.activecollab.com/docs/manuals/admin-version-3/configuration/outgoing-mail-setup